# What's the advantage of props in VS props out?

Tags: multirotor

I've heard that the quad will handle better if you reverse the propeller direction (props out), but is the difference noticeable? Especially for a relatively new pilot. Should you use props out from the beginning if you aren't used to one or the other yet?

Are there more advantages, and are there any disadvantages?

Lastly; why have props in become the standard if props out seem to be better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far I know the only difference is on the whoops. They fly much better on props out.
On 2,5-5 inch quads, it doesn't matter. Props in: our camera is dirty, you can stack easier on the tree. Props out: Your flight controller is dirty and then you damage your prop it's a higher risk that pice of the prop damage your flight controller or battery (it is a much higher risk).
Greatings form DE.

Answer (score 8):

The primary reason that I fly props out is to use the props to push the quad away from trees/gates etc when flying forward.

There is a theory that because the leading edges of the rear props are on the outside that it might compensate for the dirty air coming from the front props in forward flight as well, but I've never noticed any difference in flight on anything bigger than a whoop.

Answer (score 2):

For outdoor quads, the question one must ask is where you want grass and other debris.  If the front/rear of the quad (often where cameras and video antenna hardware is present) is something you want to avoid, run props out.  If you're more concerned about keeping the sides of the electronics stack cleaner and don't have the lens of a camera in the prop plane to absorb junk, props in works quite well.

In hybrid configurations, there are some very minor advantages of the rear props having cleaner air available in props-out configurations, and there are a few mixer edge cases with one corner at maximum commanded thrust where the yaw input matches better, but similar ones in turns where it's not as ideal.
All that aside, really it comes down to where you can tolerate high-speed plant material, sandy grit, and broken polycarbonate peppering the middle of your quadcopter.

Answer (score 0):

It does make a difference for 5" quads.  Here is a good video explaining why...
Inverted Prop Rotation - Quad Theory

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPuFGK_dEXE

Comment: While this theory has been posited, there is very little support for it in practicality. Data logging on quads with props-in vs props-out shows no difference on larger quads, and there is no detectable difference in handling. It seems to only make a difference practically on smaller quads with lower power-to-weight ratios regardless of the theory.

Comment: Please include at least a brief summary of the information you are referring to and refrain from pasting in only links. Thanks!